# Two div with the same class name, how can I scrape only the first class instance?

Tags: javascript, x-ray

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
    var x = Xray();
    var a = false;


    var url = "abcdeabcde";

            x(url, '.listing_risultati_prodotti .smcc-listing-risultati-prodotto', [{
                title: '.first-col  a',
                link: '.product-description a@href',
                prezzo: '.second-col .ish-priceContainer-salePrice'
            }])(function(err, obj) {
                console.log(obj)   
            })
```

The query right now return two times the same value because there are two div that match the query.

```
[ { title: 'aaaa',
    link: 'aaaa',
    prezzo: 'aaaa' },
  { title: 'bbb',
    link: 'bbb',
    prezzo: ' bbb' },
  { title: 'ccc',
    link: 'ccc',
    prezzo: 'ccc' },
.....
....
.....
Then again
{ title: 'aaaa',
    link: 'aaaa',
    prezzo: 'aaaa' },
  { title: 'bbb',
    link: 'bbb',
    prezzo: ' bbb' },
  { title: 'ccc',
    link: 'ccc',
    prezzo: 'ccc' }]
```

both div have same selector path

```
#maincontent > div.category-section > div.render-category-products.products > div.listing_risultati_prodotti
```

They are both nested inside this id: `#smcc_comp_common_wrapper`

structure is like:

```
<body>
#smcc_comp_common_wrapper
...
...
#mainwrapper
    ...
    #maincontent > div.category-section > div.render-category-products.products > div.listing_risultati_prodotti 
    ...
#mainwrapper
    ...
    #maincontent > div.category-section > div.render-category-products.products > div.listing_risultati_prodotti 
    ...
...
...
```

i'm trying something like:

```
x(url, '.listing_risultati_prodotti:nth-of-type(1) .smcc-listing-risultati-prodotto',
```

or also

`x(url, ':nth-match(1 of #mainwrapper) .listing_risultati_prodotti .smcc-listing-risultati-prodotto',` but no one works

Is possible targeting only the first class instance?

Comment: have you tried using `:first-child`
I mean like this  `.listing_risultati_prodotti:first-child`

Comment: Careful though, first-child takes the element if it is the first child of its parent. It doesn't take the first element of a selection.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is:

```
x(html, 'div#smcc_comp_common_wrapper div#mainwrapper:first-of-type div.listing_risultati_prodotti'
    )(function(err, obj) {
        console.log(obj) 
    })
```

also there should not be multiple elements with the same id

Answer (score 0):

If any solution which uses selectors (e.g. using `:first-child` as Vaibhav suggested) fails, how about just slicing the resultant object array in half?

```
function(err, obj) {
    var half = obj.splice(obj.length/2);
}
```

Note, that it is a kind of a workaround for your problem, however it may be acceptable in that particular case.

- [Array splice() method reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Comment: if i don't find other solution i'm gonna use this one, but like you said is a workaround